# Would EntityManager.find(id) execute malicious attack?

Tags: java, rest, xss, sql-injection, checkmarx

My rest services take "ids" parameter from the UI. My controller is as below

```
@RestOutMessage
deleteEntry(List<String> ids) {
    .......
}
```

I ran Checkmarx on my app and it highlighted "ids" and reported that it is vulnerable to XSS and other HTML injection attacks.

Internally my code used `entityManager.delete(id)`.
I am not sure if this is safe or how can I explain this is safe.

Comment: XSS and HTML injection occur on the client-facing model, not the server-side model.

Comment: Thanks , but I get "Id" from the UI

Comment: If you have any sort of transaction coming from the UI, then yes, an attacker can piggy back off client-side XSS to attack your database.

Comment: Try to add more code so we can see the entire suspected attack vector. Also, the full description of the Checkmarx warning may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with checkmarx, but to the heart of your question. I don't really see how this line of code could be related to XSS or HTML injection. You should probably only worry about SQL injection, and on that front you're safe -  Hibernate uses PreparedStatement's underneath.